# How to connect QgsMapLayerComboBox to QgsDataDefinedButton

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt, qt-designer

in Qt Designer there is the possibility to use directly **QGIS custom widgets**.

In the UI I added a `QgsMapLayerComboBox` (to get the layers added in the legend) and a `QgsDataDefinedButton`.

What I would like to do is to connect the `QgsDataDefinedButton` to the `QgsMapLayerComboBox` so that the `QgsDataDefinedButton` should be updated with the fields of the selected layer of the `QgsMapLayerComboBox`.

While connecting `QgsMapLayerComboBox` to a `QgsFieldComboBox` or a `QgsFieldExpressionComboBox` is not a problem through the singal - slot combination:

```
layerCHanged(QgsMapLayer*) -> setLayer(QgsMapLayer*)
```

I'm not able to to that with the `QgsDataDefinedButton`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the qgis-dev mailing list and to Denis Rouzaud, this is the answer..

```
class MyDialogClass(UiClass):
  def __init__(self):
    self.setupUi()
    self.myLayerComboBox.layerChanged.connect(self.myConnectMethod)

  @pyqtSlot(QgsVectorLayer)
  def myConnectMethod(self, layer)
    self.myDataDefinedButton.init(layer, .....)
```

so the link between the 2 widgets could not be made through Qt Designer and has to be written within the code.

Hope this could help someone else.